# Failed to construct instance from factory method SparkRunner#fromOptions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I am getting the following exception in java in Apache beam, using Spark as a Runner. I commented the erroneous line.

```
PipelineOptions o = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
SparkContextOptions options = o.as(SparkContextOptions.class);

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("test");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
options.setUsesProvidedSparkContext(true);
options.setProvidedSparkContext(jsc);

Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options); //Error in this line
```

Above is the code and below is the error !!

> `3639 [main] INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@18324f97{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method SparkRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:55)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:150)
>           at com.svayamtech.bean_app.Wordcount_lambda.main(Wordcount_lambda.java:42)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
>           ... 4 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/runners/core/construction/PipelineResources
>           at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.fromOptions(SparkRunner.java:129)
>           ... 9 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineResources
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 10 more
>       3690 [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
>       3696 [Thread-1] INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Stopped Spark@78f9ed3e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}`

Spark Runner is not working ? Can Anyone help me in this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your all beam spacific jars with your SparkContext.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]")
  .setAppName("test").setJars(Seq("beam-runners-core-construction-java-2.5.0.jar"));
```

Comment: I am using Maven and i added all the dependencies

Comment: Not in Maven, you have to explicitly specify all the jars or if you so many jars, you create a shade jar and pass to conf.

Comment: Or you can add like this also `.conf("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.5.0")`